# Browser to Phone Calls Microsoft Teams (Communication API) C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am attempting to make a browser to phone call using microsoft teams communication api. I have gone through the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and it suggests to create a calling bot.
I'm not sure if registering the bot on teams is necessary as I don't want the bot to participate in calls I need it purely for initiating 1:1 calls (myself to another user)

1. Is it possible to make browser to phone calls using [communications-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)
2. Any sample guiding implementation of this functionality

Comment: I assume when you say browser, you are referring to Teams in browser.
You can not create any 1:1 call without bot. All the communication api need a bot.

Comment: I have a US number associated with my teams account, I can go to Calls > Dial a number and make call to any US phone number. I need this to be achieved in our web app programatically i.e. calling a phone number while staying on web. I fount this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/pstn-call?pivots=platform-web but its a different approach and doesnt use my teams number.

Comment: Currently this is not possible, you can raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)